# What is the Abominable Snowman's real name?

Tags: disney, monsters-inc

In Monster's Inc, Mike and Sully encounter The Abominable Snowman, who apparently takes offense to that name.

> Abominable. Can you believe that? Do I look abominable to you? Why can't they call me the Adorable Snowman, or the Agreeable Snowman, for crying out loud? I'm a nice guy.

[The IMDB page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0198781/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) lists the character as being called "The Abominable Snowman", but the dialog indicates that he has another name.

Has his real name ever been revealed?

Answer (score 9):

He seems to have been called Abominable Snowman before he left the Monster world.

From the movie transcript:

> **Mike**: Loch Ness, Bigfoot, the Abominable Snowman...
>   they all got one thing in common, pal... banishment.

Mike says this long before he himself gets banished.

The Abominable Snowman is also a character in Monsters University. And he is referred to as Mr. Snowman.

> **The Abominable Snowman**: Alright newbies, quit goofing around. I'll have you know, tampering with the mail, is a crime punishable by banishment!
>   **Sulley**: Yes, sir!
>   **Mike**: We're right on it, Mr. Snowman!

Comment: I think since Mike uses the Abominable Snowman in the exiled list that means that it's his name/title rather than the name of his species.

Comment: The fact that he also references "Loch Ness" goes against the idea that it was his name prior to exile. For the real name to be "Loch Ness", then the loch itself has to be either named after the monster, or there has to be one HUGE coincidence.

Comment: Abominable also mentions his good friend Bigfoot.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this wiki page](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Yeti_(Monsters,_Inc.)) his name is **Yeti**.

[Apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeti) that is a common name for the creature:

> The Yeti or Abominable Snowman (Nepali: हिममानव, lit. "mountain man") is an ape-like cryptid taller than an average human that is said to inhabit the Himalayan region of Nepal and Tibet. The names Yeti and Meh-Teh are commonly used by the people indigenous to the region, and are part of their history and mythology. Stories of the Yeti first emerged as a facet of Western popular culture in the 19th century.

That is not the name he is given in the Monsters Inc credits, but it does match those for Monsters University:

- [Monsters Inc IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0198781/)

  > John Ratzenberger ... The Abominable Snowman (voice)
- [Monsters University IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1453405/fullcredits/)

  > John Ratzenberger ... Yeti (voice)

Comment: To me, the fact that it identifies him as *The Yeti* and mentions that the names "are commonly used by the people indigenous to the region" give more sway to the idea that neither are his real name, and just what he is commonly called by humans, or is otherwise a sort of title. After all, it's "Mike Wazowski", not "*The Mike Wazowski*" (well, in anyone's head except for Mike's).

Comment: @phantom42 - I hear you, although for what it's worth the cast listing for Monsters University is "Yeti" not "The Yeti".

Comment: How do you account for Mike calling him Mr. Snowman?

Comment: @JackBNimble Maybe "Snowman" really *is* part of his name, but "Abominable" isn't.